# APPCRASH (c0000005) in program when function loses scope

Tags: c, scanf, crash

When I left out the second parameter on the scanf() function by mistake, the program still compiled and ran but the executable experienced the following error: "APPCRASH" with the exception code "c0000005" (which means there was a memory access violation AFAIK). I did some experimenting and it seemed the crash always happened when the functions calling scanf() went out of scope but I've since realised it happens more on the actual call than not. Example:

```
void afunction (void) {
    printf("This works fine!");
    scanf("%c");               /* NOTE the second parameter omission */
    printf("This showed up a few times, misleading me");
}
```

I now have three questions:

1) Why does the compiler not fail to compile the code? It doesn't even warn me!

2) Is scanf() trying to write to memory address NULL now? eg: scanf("%c", NULL)

3) Why did / how did anything below the failed scanf() statement manage to execute??

Additional information: 
Platform: Windows
Compiler: GCC
IDE: Code::Blocks

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: I'm asking:
a) Why the compiler didn't notice that the second parameter was missing in scanf(), ie: "Why does the compiler, GCC in my case, not pick this up and refuse to compile..."
b) Does scanf() to write to NULL (like when you try and write to a NULL-pointer, ie: "...does this mean that scanf() will try to write to NULL if no 2nd parameter is passed?"

I get that maybe I wafted on a little and I'm sorta seeing now the badly-phraed parts but I don't feel that the question was that bad. Maybe someone could give me an explanation of what I did wrong so I don't mess up again?

Comment: To get a better response in future, try to include code which demonstrates the problem you're describing.  And be much clearer about what the problem is.  A "c0000005 error" is pretty much meaningless; if people don't understand what you've done or what the result was, it's unlikely you'll get helpful responses.  Try looking at up-voted questions on the site and consider how they differ from your question.

Comment: Okay, I'm going to try edit my question then, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

#### "Why does the compiler not fail to compile the code? It doesn't even warn me!"

That is because the signature for scanf() is `int scanf ( const char * format, ... );` the `...` represents the [varargs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stdarg.h) and zero argument is a valid varargs too. Seems like gcc is not smart enough to parse the format string at compile time and generate warnings.

#### "Is scanf() trying to write to memory address NULL now? eg: scanf("%c", NULL)"

This is most likely implementation dependent, but most likely it will just try to read some data off the stack where the first parameter with the format string was.

#### "Why did / how did anything below the failed scanf() statement manage to execute??"

When the `scanf()` parses the first argument and detect that it will need a pointer it will get some uninitialized memory back random garbage in it and if you are "lucky" you get a "valid" address somewhere in your program's memory and it won't segfault right away. This is really unfortunate since (as you could see) sometimes will fail sometimes it don't. These kind of memory corruptions are hard to track down since the point where the error will surface might not have any connection to the point it happened.

Comment: Thanks, that actually make sense now. Guess I'll have to be careful when debugging my code.